# gulp の task を失敗させるには?

Tags: node.js, gulp

`gulp.task()` を失敗終了するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
具体的には外部プロセスが終了コード0以外で終了したときにtaskを失敗させたい（gulpの実行をそこで止めたい）です。

次のようなtaskを想定しています。

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('mytask', function() {
  var proc = spawn('my_command');
  proc.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    if (code !== null && code !== 0) {
      // ここで gulp task を失敗させたい
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: 失敗させるには、`function(done) {... if (!code) done('error');`いいでしょう。[参考](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693266/marking-async-task-as-failed-and-have-gulp-exit-with-non-zero-exit-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gulp.task()` に渡す関数の第１引数が非同期処理用のコールバックになっているので、そいつを呼べば抜けるかもしれません。

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('mytask', function(done) {
  var proc = spawn('my_command');
  proc.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    if (code !== null && code !== 0) {
      done('error'); // タスク失敗。引数が null じゃなければ失敗
    } else {
      done(); // タスク正常終了
    }
  });
});
```

[ドキュメント](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md)には

> if ... not null and not undefined, the orchestration will stop

とあります。ただ、注意点として、処理の流れの中で最後に `done` 関数が必ず呼ばれるようにしてください。例外のほうが万能かも。

Comment: [APIのドキュメント](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#accept-a-callback)にも、記述がありますね。(v3, v4ともに)
タスク内の表記としてはコールバックがキレイな気がしてきました。

Answer (score 2):

プラグインであれば`gulp-util`の`PluginError`を使いますが、タスク内に直接JavaScriptで記述するケースであれば、例外を投げるだけで良いと思います。

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('mytask', function() {
  var proc = spawn('ls');
  proc.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    if (code !== null && code !== 0) {
      throw 'Error!';
    }
  });
});
```

参考まで、[PluginErrorのソースコード](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util/blob/master/lib/PluginError.js)はこちらです。